# PHP MYSQL LOOP (insert TABLE_C) FROM QUERY RESULT TABLE_A and TABLE_B

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, while-loop

i have 3 tables table_a(4000 rows) and table_b(35000 rows) and table_c to store the result,
it takes 670 sec to complete...., is there another way to do this..?,( i also try left join , but the right table give result more than one, and the left result become more than one, and it takes about 300 sec to complete.....

autocommit = 0

```
$c_mgp = "select * from table_a where .......";
$c_mgp_r = mysqli_query($con_a,$c_mgp) or die (mysqli_error($con_a));
$multi_sq = '';
    $r = 0;
while($c_mgp_f = mysqli_fetch_array($c_mgp_r)) {
    $r++;
    $mgpstat = trim($c_mgp_f['STATUS']);
    $mgpval= trim($c_mgp_f['VAL']);
            $sand = trim(($c_mgp_f['SAND']);

$multi_sq .= "insert into table_c (NAME,VAL,VAL_RES) values('$mgpstat','$mgpval',
                  (select SUM(VAL_RES) from table_b where DATE = '$date_a' and GRUP = '$grup' and ACNO= '$sand'));" //this part is the most important thing, $sand always different (and always more than one row in result) each loop
if($r == 500){
    mysqli_multi_query...........;
    $r=0;
    $multi_sq='';
    }

  }
```

commit

many thanks for the help...

Comment: Have you considered using [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: isn't it what he does in `$multi_sp= ...` ?

Comment: shouldn't there be a `GROUP BY ...` in the `SELECT SUM(...` ?

Comment: thx for the reply, and for Felix Gagnon, results in select(sum..  are integer value (money currency), is there other way to approach-->..."insert into table_c (cola,colb,,VAL_RES) values (vala,valb,(select sum(VAL_RES), GRUP from...where........group by GRUP));